# Normal subgroup and cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Hello friends: I have a skeleton proof from lectures to the following question:

> Let $[G:A]$ be finite. Prove that there exists a Normal subgroup $N \trianglelefteq G$ s.t. $N \subset A$ and $[G:N]$ is finite.

So in lectures, the skeleton proof goes like this:

> For simplicity assume $[G:A]=3$, so write $G=\cup\{A,xA,yA\}$ for some $x,y \in G.$

Consider the permutation $\phi: g \to \{gA,gxA,gyA\}$, prove it's a homomorphism. And observe that First kernel of $\phi$ is normal in $G$. Second, $g\in \ker(\phi)$ implies $\{gA,gxA,gyA\} = \{A,xA,yA\}$, which implies $gA=A$,  which implies $g \in A$, so $\ker(\phi) \in A$. Then we choose $N=\ker(\phi).$

By 1-st isomorphism theorem, $\frac{G}{\ker(\phi)} \cong {\rm im} \phi \in S_{p} (finite)$, so $|\frac{G}{N}|$ is finite.

I am particularly confused about the permutation and $S_{p}$ symbol here. One of my friends told me it's actually about group action, which we have not covered in lectures. So could some one please explain to me a little bit about the permutation $\phi$ and how the proof here flows in the right direction? I feel a bit confused.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the edit~

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to choose a set of representatives of the cosets, say $\{x_1=1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$, where $n=[G:A]$. Thus any coset has the form $x_iA$, for a unique $i$.

If $g\in G$, then we can define, for $1\le i\le n$, $\hat{g}(i)=j$ if and only if $gx_iA=x_jA$. Thus $\hat{g}$ is a permutation of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, hence an element of $S_n$, the group of permutations on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

In this way we have defined a map $\phi\colon G\to S_n$, where $\phi(g)=\hat{g}$. Prove it is a homomorphism.

If $g\in\ker\phi$, then, by definition, $\hat{g}$ is the identity map, which means that $gx_iA=x_iA$, for every $i$. This is true, in particular, for $x_1=1$, which means $gA=A$, so $g\in A$.

Therefore $\ker\phi\subseteq A$. Moreover, by the homomorphism theorem, $G/\ker\phi$ embeds in $S_n$, so $[G:\ker\phi]$ is finite. Hence $N=\ker\phi$ is a possible choice for a subgroup satisfying the requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much. I totally understand this right now. By the way,  you say it's a possible choice , do you know is there any other elementary way to prove this claim?

Comment: @chicago I just wanted to stress that this is *a* subgroup satisfying the requirements; I don't think it's generally unique.